# You can't specify target table 'person' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I need to delete duplicate emails.

In SQLite this is correct sql query:

```
delete from person 
where id in (select id from person 
group by email
having count(email) > 1)
```

But when I try to use same query on MySQL I get error:

```
You can't specify target table 'person' for update in FROM clause
```

P.S. I also try by inner join but it not help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self join of the tables like this:

```
delete p1 
from person p1 inner join person p2
on p2.email = p1.email and p2.id < p1.id
```

or:

```
delete p
from person p 
inner join (
  select email, min(id) id
  from person
  group by email
) t on t.email = p.email and t.id < p.id
```

Comment: Not delete duplicate rows

Comment: See my edited answer or clarify what you want to delete.

Comment: @a_subscriber I think that you want my 2nd query.

Comment: Not delete duplicate emails

Comment: Then post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: This is not the deletion of the duplicate emails because you want to keep 1. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try uing a delete JOIN  with your subquery

```
Delete person 
from person 
INNER JOIN  (
    select id 
    from person 
    group by email
    having count(email) > 1
) t  on t.id = person.id
```

Using your syntax you delete a row  that is used by the subquery  (the in clause)  .. using a inner join on the same subqiery  the values are copied  in temporary table and you  resolve the conflict